# Cross-Merge Many Videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing, video-encoding

I have one folder with 30 videos, and another with 4. I want to merge the 30 first video as an intro to the 4, in order to create 120 different videos. In other words, imagine letters are intro videos and numbers the base video.

**Folder 1**: A, B, C ...

**Folder 2**: 1, 2, 3, 4

**Output**: A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3 ...

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Need to know your OS. Does "cross-merge" mean you want a crossfade?

Comment: @llogan I'm using iOS, but can go to Windows if needed. I didn't mean crossfade, but simple merge across many different videos. Thanks so much for your advice :)

Comment: Do all inputs have the same attributes?

Answer (score 0):

With *Merge* you mean to concatenate...

*Intro_A + Video_1*

*Intro_B + Video_1*

*Intro_C + Video_1*

*Intro_A + Video_2* and so on

I have a bash script that can do that.

Do you have a **shell** ready?

Comment: I don't have a shell, I'm completely new to all of this! More than willing to put in the research and learn though :) Thanks so much Drake

Comment: You're welcome. On what system are you using ffmpeg at the moment?